# Drop Down menu in Jquery

Tags: jquery

hello friends i have tryied folowing code as u can see here http://jsfiddle.net/QCdz4/ i want to code for drop down menu to appear on `click()` and  disappear when `mouseout()` but its not working  please help me out Thank in advance

Jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.click ul').css({display:'none', position:'absolute'});
        $('.click').click(function() {
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown(200);
            $(this).on('mouseout', function() {
                $(this).children('ul').slideUp(200);
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="click">
    click
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I really wonder why you need to do something like that.

Comment: @SadullahCeran yes i know this is weird to use this code for drop down menu but problem is in my web page there is lots of jqueries and lots of plugins are used and there is so many conflict problems so thats why i m asking this kind of question ..  so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need mouseleave instead of mouseout because mouseout will also be triggered when you hover from the parent to a child element. The child element positioned above (read: z-index) the parent. Moving the cursor in this case from parent to child element will trigger the mouseout event but not the mouseleave event. The mouseleave element will only be triggered when you move the cursor away from the parent AND it's children.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.click ul').css({display:'none', position:'absolute'});


   $('.click').on('click', function(){
       $("ul", $(this)).slideDown(200);
   }).on('mouseleave', function(){
       $("ul", $(this)).slideUp(200);
   });   


})
```

Update: A very good article with a very clear live demo can be found here: [Different between mouseout and mouseleave in jquery](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/).
(Check out the the square's with child elements. The one on the bottom right)

Comment: wow its working fine .. can u plz explain what is diffrence between mouseleave nad mouseout sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: Check the update in my answer. You can read and see the difference very well on that page. I'm happy I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click ul').css({display:'none', position:'absolute'});
$('.click').click(function(){

     $(this).children('ul').slideDown(200);
})

$('.click ul').hover(
  function () {
    // do nothing
  }, 
  function () {
    $('.click ul').slideUp(200);
  }
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are chaining your function the wrong way.

```
$('.click').click(function(){
     $(this).children('ul').slideDown(200);
}).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp(200);
});
```

Improving the above code,

```
$('.click').on('click', function(){
     $("ul", $(this)).slideDown(200);
}).on('mouseout', function(){
    $("ul", $(this)).slideUp(200);
});
```

---

**Update**

To ensure a event triggers once the cursor is outside the element, you have to use mouseleave instead of mouse out

```
$('.click').on('click', function(){
     $("ul", $(this)).slideDown(200);
}).on('mouseleave', function(e){
        $("ul", $(this)).slideUp(200);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QCdz4/4)

Comment: thanks for help @Starx but its not working as u can see when u click on it the <ul> slide down but when i going to click on drropped <ul> its slideup .. this the error i m facing

Answer (score 0):

Move the binding of mouseout event outside binding of click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

$('.click ul').css({display:'none', position:'absolute'});

$('.click').click(function(){

```
 $(this).children('ul').slideDown(200);
```

})
$('.click').on('mouseout', function(){

$(this).children('ul').slideUp(200);
})

})​